# Change app language programmatically WITHOUT restarting the app

Tags: swift

When I change the language from my app it doesn't take effect until I close the app and restart it. I don't want to restart it. I tried also presenting rootViewController but doesn't work. Is there any solution?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We would need to see your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the language in every Single of ViewControllers inside `ViewDidLoad()` So when User Clicked on the purposed Language Save it with `UserDefaults.standard.set("En", forKey: "languages")` So when you've saved languages You can Get the Selected languages by  `UserDefaults.standard.String(forKey: "languages")` Which will give you En String Value

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       //Get Language Func 
       GetLanguage()
 }

 @IBAction func ChangeToEn(_ sender:Any) {
        SaveSelectedLanguage(SomeString: "En")
}

 func SaveSelectedLanguage(SomeString:String) {
        //Save Selected Language 
        UserDefaults.standard.set("En", forKey: SomeString)
        //GetResult By Get Language Func 
        GetLanguage()
}

 func GetLanguage {
        //initializing
        Switch UserDefualts.standard.string(forkey:"languages") {
        case "En":
        lbl.text = "Hello World"
        case "Tr":
        lbl.text = "Merhaba Dunya"
        case "Fa"
        lbl.text = "سلام دنیا" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this true but how about when you change it like in settings using a `UISwitch`. How would you refresh the whole up to update it to the changed language instead of closing the app

Comment: I have upload a project on GitHub in this link


   https://github.com/alirezanmz/Change-Language-Without-Closing-App please rate if it's going to solve your problem rate the project on Github Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the phone language once the app is lunch **like in settings**

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var HeadTitle: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //when You are trying to change the language
    //Get Phone Language
    GetPhoneLanguage()
    //Get Language
    GetLanguege()
}

@IBAction func SaveEn(_ sender: Any) {
    SaveLanguage(Value: "en")
    GetLanguege()
}

@IBAction func SaveTr(_ sender: Any) {
    SaveLanguage(Value: "tr")
    GetLanguege()
}

func SaveLanguage(Value:String){
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Value, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

func GetPhoneLanguage(){
    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleLanguages") == nil {
    let preferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages[0] as String
    print (preferredLanguage) //en-US
    let arr = preferredLanguage.components(separatedBy: "-")
    let deviceLanguage = arr.first
    UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceLanguage!, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    }
}

func GetLanguege() {
    switch UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "AppleLanguages") {
    case "en":
        HeadTitle.text = "Hello World"
    case "tr":
        HeadTitle.text = "Merhaba Dunya"
    default:
    print("No Languages")
    }
}
```

}